# SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token vm.js?

Tags: node.js

Непонятная ошибка.

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { MZ�

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:537:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:609:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:598:3
```

Comment: А зачем вы пытаетесь по-require-ить exe файл?

Comment: Понял,child Process fork пытается запустить файл как модуль node js, а не просто сторонний процесс.

Comment: Да. Вам нужен `spawn`